# Assimp library usage documents

Tags: c, visual-studio, api, opengl

I found a library called  [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) for parsing a lot of 3D model file formats that I could use to import to OpenGL. It seem a good and stable libray but the usage documents are so poor. Can someone tell me how I use this library to import a obj (or another) model? Or just give me a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found their documentation to actually be quite good, albeit hard to navigate. Check out the [usage page](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/usage.html) for how to get started.

Comment: their documentation do not tell how data was stored in classes and so on i don't know how to render from that data.

Comment: @Binh: [Sure it does.](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html) On this page is a description of what aiMesh stores. The page for the [aiMesh data structure](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_mesh.html) is also useful, as it goes into greater detail.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for reply!, Can you glances this (http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp) page and explains me why they use recursive_render function for scan all aiNode struct but not `for (int i=0; i<scene->mNumMesh; ++i) {draw scene->mMeshed[i];}` method?. Sorry for inconvenient :-(

Comment: They need to learn how to make a menu.  The original poster was correct, their documentation layout is poorly done.  You need to read down near the bottom of the main page to find a link to the page for the data, no menu.